# Generating graphs favouring unique cliques

Tags: python, c++, networkx, graph-theory, igraph

For a research project I am working on, I need to generate random graphs which favour forming cliques without the largest cliques containing the same nodes. For instance, the Barabási–Albert model can generate graphs containing large cliques, but those cliques have mainly the same nodes because of preferential attachment.

Although I prefer using existing packages like Networkx or IGraph, I am okay with implementing research papers that have formalised generating such networks. The only criterium is that the generation of those graphs should not take more than 15 seconds for a graph with, for instance, 10.000 nodes and an average degree of 100.

I am also not sure if I should ask this question on here or on https://math.stackexchange.com/, so say so if I need to ask it over there.

Comment: There's also https://cs.stackexchange.com for computer science. But if you're looking for actual code to generate the graph, stackoverflow is probably more suited.

Comment: I expect this question will get closed here because it is a research question, not a programming question. Math.SE would be better. But before you re-post it, I think you should clarify what you mean by "without the largest cliques containing the same nodes".  I do not understand what you want to do.

Comment: You had already probably found that page, but just in case, here are the random graph functions from networkx: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.random_graphs (Actually, there are a few random graphs on that page that are listed under something other than "random graphs", so search for "random" and for "clique" in the whole page). In particular the graphs under "community" mention cliques a lot: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.community

Comment: I will also suggest that you should think carefully about what you mean by "random graphs" with "property X" (for whatever X, e.g. some requirements on cliques). Do you want to sample _uniformly_ from the set of graph which satisfy your property? If not, then what do you plan to do with these graphs? If your sampling is biased (non-uniform), will your results be meaningful? This already shows why this question is not for StackOverflow.

Comment: If you mean "non-overlapping cliques", this might come close: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.82.066118

Comment: Thank you Stef and Szabolcs. I will look first through cs.stackexchange.com, and if I can not find anything relating to my question, I will ask it either on cs.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com. With the part "without the largest cliques containing the same nodes", I mean that, for instance, if the ten largest maximal cliques contain between 8 and 12 nodes, the number of unique found in this set of cliques should be at least 40.

Comment: Suggested algorithm: 1) Generate a random "overlapping partition" of your set of nodes; 2) Each subset from the partition becomes a clique; 3) Possibly add a few more random edges with low probability. Here is a research paper which I have not read but claims to generate overlapping partitions: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3869364_On_overlapping_partitions

Comment: @Stef I will look into the paper. Both you and Szabolcs helped me quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It does rather depend on what you mean by random.

However, here is an algorithm for generating graphs with large cliques that do not share nodes and have some specified amount of "randomness"

```
Input number of cliques required ( or random distribution specs for same )
Input number of nodes in each clique ( or random distribution specs for same )
LOOP over number of cliques
   LOOP over number of nodes in clique
        Add node to graph
   Add links between every pair of nodes in clique
LOOP c1 over cliques
    LOOP c2 over c1+1 to number of cliques
        SELECT a random node in c1 and c2
        Link nodes in c1 and c2
```

The c1 loop ensure that the graph is completely connected.  Don't know if you want that.  It creates one link between each pair of cliques.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible algorithm to generate a graph of partially-overlapping cliques.

I strongly encourage you to tweak it so that it better suits the intuition for a random distribution that you might have in head.

```py
from itertools import combinations
from itertools import pairwise # or def pairwise(a): return zip(a, a[1:])
import random
import networkx as nx

def random_graph(n_nodes, n_cliques, p_overlap):
    a = [0] + random.sample(range(n_nodes), n_cliques-1) + [n_nodes]  # split points
    cliques = [set(range(i,j)) for i,j in pairwise(a)]                # partition
    nodes = set(range(n_nodes))
    for c in cliques:
        c.update(random.sample(nodes - c, round(p_overlap * len(c)))) # add random nodes from other cliques
    G = nx.Graph()
    for c in cliques:
        G.add_edges_from(combinations(c, 2))
    return G

# Can add some randomness by replacing round(p_overlap * len(c)) with a random.gauss()

# TESTING
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = random_graph(20, 4, 0.1)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

[image: random clique graph with 20 nodes and 4 overlapping cliques]